# Jest disable massive dump of html element on error

Tags: javascript, jestjs, stimulusjs

I'm testing a stimulus controller with jest. Every time it gets an error, it dumps EVERY property of an HTML element, which is impossible to read and I can't see the error because it exceeds my scrollback buffer.

Output:

```
...lots..
      HTMLBRElement: [Function],
              HTMLButtonElement: [Function],
              HTMLCanvasElement: [Function],
              HTMLDataElement: [Function],
              HTMLDataListElement: [Function],
              HTMLDetailsElement: [Function],
              HTMLDialogElement: [Function],
              HTMLDirectoryElement: [Function],
              HTMLFieldSetElement: [Function],
              HTMLFontElement: [Function],
              HTMLFormElement: [Function],
... more ..
```

It's possible to redirect that output to a file, but I only need like the top 10 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok of course. "I only need like the top 10 lines"

`yarn test test.js | head -n 40`

node complains about EPIPE but I'm happy.